# Bind Knockoutjs viewmodels across different pages dynamically loaded by jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

It is a frequently asked question I am aware however, I realized there were 3 questions always ambiguiosly answered.

1. Why don't the new pages inherently get bound?
2. What jQm (jQueryMobile) **event** should be used to identify and bind the viewmodel?
3. Why **does not** it **work** even **after I followed step 1 and step 2**

Comment: Go through [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/with-binding-magic-writing-single-page-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs/) post of mine and you will understand throughly

Comment: Thank you @raheelshan, this is a question+answer post, I've tried to explain it to the best of my knowledge, yet thank you for your post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer to the best of my knowledge

**Why don't the new pages inherently get bound?**

> Knockoutjs is not aware of any content loaded after you have bound your viewmodel. Ofcourse any change rendered within the viewmodel is tracked but new bindings cannot be applied to any **external** content
>
> Note the "**external**" keyword. jQm offers to maintain multiple pages in the same document using different `div` with different `pageID`, all these pages are inherently bound because knockoutjs does not care about the jQm rendering of pages.

**What jQm event should be used to identify and bind the viewmodel?**

Depending on your requirement use any of the page events to perform this, however I find the load event `$('.selector').on('pagecontainerload',function(event,ui){...});` quite useful. Here below is a sample code.

```
$('body').on('pagecontainerload', function (event, ui) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#externalPageID')[0]);
});
```

Note that `externalPageID` is not the name of the document but the `pageID` within the document. Also note that the `applyBindings` method does not take a selector as the second argument but a javascript object and hence the `[0]`.

**Why doesn't it work even after I followed step 1 and step 2**

You are not alone, it did not work for me either. Though `pagecontainerload` event fires after the page is loaded and enhanced by jQm there is a very short lag before the page is accessible by the `applyBindings` method. I do not know why and I request any suggestions or comments on this. Luckily there is a workaround though, here below is a sample code

```
$('body').on('pagecontainerload', function (event, ui) {
    waitToLoad(ui.page[0].id);
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel); //bind the initial page

function waitToLoad(pageID) {
    if ($('#' + pageID).length > 0) {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + pageID)[0]); //bind the external page
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () { waitToLoad(pageID); }, 100);
    }
}
```

The above piece of code binds the initial page immediately and whenever a new page is loaded, it is also bound. But make sure that you do not bind a page which is already bound, the situation is less likely but it could happen if you force reload a page in the DOM. Make sure you handle that manually.